# ngx-bootstrap nested accordions not updating height when animated

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

When trying to have nested accordions on using ngx-bootstrap content is cut if isAnimated is set to true, setting it to false works normally.

Is there a way to work around this?

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-playground-ehupfc?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest%2Ftest.component.html)